# Como poner mi funcion ToString de una clase en un messagebox de un de una listbox de un formulario?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Explico con mas detalles. 
Tengo una clase llamada CDocumentoXPagar.

```
        public string SerieDocumento { get; set; }
        public int CorrelativosDelDocumento { get; set; }
        public string FechaDeVencimiento { get; set; }
        public string FechaDeFacturacion { get; set; }
        public string CondicionDePagoDelDocumento { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Nro Serie del documento:{0}\tCorrelativos del Documento:{1}\tFecha de vencimiento:{2}\tFecha de facturación: {3}\tCondiciones de pago del documento: {4}", SerieDocumento, CorrelativosDelDocumento, FechaDeVencimiento, FechaDeFacturacion, CondicionDePagoDelDocumento);
        }
```

Y una clase llamada CProveedor donde existe una Lista de Documentos.

```
 public class CProvedor
    {
        public string RUC { get; set; }
        public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
        public  List<CDocumentoXPagar> ListaDocumentos { get; set; }
        public CProvedor() {
            ListaDocumentos = new List<CDocumentoXPagar>(); }
      }
```

Finalmente tengo una Clase que tiene una lista de CProveedores

```
class CLista
    {
        public static List<CProvedor> ListaProvedores{get;set;}
        public static List<CDocumentoXPagar> Documentos { get; set; }
        public CLista()
        {
            if (ListaProvedores == null)
                ListaProvedores = new List<CProvedor>();
            if (Documentos == null)
                Documentos = new List<CDocumentoXPagar>();
        }
        public void RegistrarProvedor(CProvedor provedor)
        {
            ListaProvedores.Add(provedor);
        }


        public void InsertarDocumentoEnProveedor(string _RUC, CDocumentoXPagar documento) {
//... etc (Mas funciones para listar, ordenar, etc)
```

En un formulario tengo una listbox. Lo que quiero es que al seleccionar cierto elemento de una lista y presionar un boton, me de detalles acerca de el documento. El problema es que no se como hacer que todo ese ToString aparezca en esa messagebox. He intentado esto:

```
Clista = objLista = new CLista();
.
.
.
 private void btnDetalles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ToString());

            }
        }
```

Quisiera que me puedan decir alguna forma para mostrar la funcion ToString en esa messageboc. Cualquien respuesta que ayude es bienvenida. Gracias de antemano

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que quieres hacer, debes tener en cuenta que la función .ToString() lo que hace es convertir ciertos tipos de datos a tipo string.

Comment: Pero alli veo que tienes dos veces la lista de `CDocumentoXPagar`, una como propiedad `ListaDocumentos ` en `CProvedor` y otra lista `Documentos ` en `CLista`. cual estas listando en el `listbox` ?